# Ubuntu python-dateutil install/upgrade issue. dateutil.zoneinfo.gettz returning NoneType

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I am having trouble with python dateutil.zoneinfo module.
Note:

- Broken Ubuntu machine is ( Ubuntu 11.04 )
- Working Ubuntu machine is ( Ubuntu 11.10 )

*Broken Ubuntu machine:*

```
In [1]: from dateutil import zoneinfo`
In [2]: from_zone = zoneinfo.gettz('UTC')
In [3]: from_zone
```

*From a working Ubuntu machine:*

```
In [1]: from dateutil import zoneinfo
In [2]: from_zone = zoneinfo.gettz('UTC')
In [3]: from_zone
Out[3]: tzfile('Etc/UTC')
```

Some Python introspection.

*Broken Ubuntu machine:*

```
In [5]: zoneinfo.ZONEINFOFILE
```

*From a working Ubuntu machine:*

```
In [4]: zoneinfo.ZONEINFOFILE
Out[4]: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_dateutil-1.5-py2.7.egg/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz'
```

More information: 
the broken machine, has upgraded from python 2.6 to python 2.7.
Doing a

```
$ locate zoneinfo
-- snip --
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dateutil/zoneinfo
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dateutil/zoneinfo
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/__init__.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2010g.tar.gz
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/dateutil/zoneinfo/zoneinfo-2011d.tar.gz
/usr/share/zoneinfo
/usr/share/pyshared/dateutil/zoneinfo
-- snip --
```

I can see the issue but I am unsure about what to do about it.
Note: I tried re-installing the python-dateutil with 'synaptic package manager' to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
from dateutil import tz
from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
print(from_zone)
# tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC')
```

Comment: tired that: still no joy
jds@jds-desktop:~$ locate python-dateutil
/usr/share/python-support/python-dateutil.public
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-dateutil_1.4.1-3_all.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-dateutil.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-dateutil.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-dateutil.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-dateutil.prerm

Comment: I get /usr/bin/python -> python2.7 &&  <module 'dateutil' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dateutil/__init__.pyc'>

Answer (score 6):

I know this is 8 months later, but I had the same issue.  My solution was to uninstall the existing version via:

`sudo pip uninstall python-dateutil`

then reinstall via

`sudo easy_install python-dateutil`

I hope this helps someone.